# ASP.net Web page error Use of unassigned local variable 'some'

Tags: c#, asp.net, razor

I have razor code like this

```
bool some;

if (IsPost == false)
{

 some = True

}
```

then html

```
<h1>@some.ToString()</h1>
```

and when i run it it get's me error
 Use of unassigned local variable 'some'

could anyone explain why? doesn't razor code executes first and then html?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Assign your variable some value.

```
bool some  = false;
```

> could anyone explain why? doesn't razor code executes first and then
>   html?

It doesn't has anything to do with Razor or HTML execution priority. Consider the following simple C# example:

```
bool some;
Console.WriteLine(some);
```

You are trying to write `some` which hasn't been assign any value. Similar is the case with `@some.ToString()`, you haven't assign it any value and the **compiler can't determine whether it will get the value inside the `if` statement.**

You can also do:

```
bool some = default(bool); //same as false for bool
```

You can also assign `some`, a value in `else` part like:

```
bool some;
bool IsPost = true;
if (IsPost == false)
{
    some = true;
}
else
{
    some = false;
}
```

Now the compiler knows that `some` will be assigned some value and your error would go away.

Not really sure but it appears you are trying to **toggle** the value of `IsPost` to `some` you can do:

```
some = !IsPost;
```

Comment: +1 'some' needs to have a value in every possible outcome. if 'IsPost' true, it doesn't have a value.

Answer (score 2):

You have not assigned any default value to `some` variable. Try to assign it like:

```
bool some = false;
```

This has nothing to do with Razor or HTML execution priority